# new Number().toFixed()) is not working properly

Tags: javascript

```js
console.log(new Number("987654321.98").toFixed(9));
```

The above line is returning **"987654321.980000019"** but I am expecting **"987654321.980000000"**

Comment: [Is floating point math broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Comment: JavaScript does not offer more precision than that. If you absolutely need it, you'll need to switch all your logic to BigInt or plain strings.